# ORA-02367: read ended but had expected more data from file [filename]

Tags: oracle

I've been provided with an Oracle backup consisting of sequential files, but I'm getting the above error when I try to restore it.

The file referenced in the error is the last file in the backup. The provider have confirmed that's the last file in the backup. The file dates seem to confirm that all files were generated in the same export.

Is there anything I can do at my end to try and resolve this?

---

```
Import: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sat Feb 17 12:40:02 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;; 
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Master table "BKUP_USER"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "BKUP_USER"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  bkup_user/******** directory=exp_table dumpfile=STRUTT_PARKER_DOCS%U.DMP TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=TRUNCATE 
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
ORA-31693: Table data object "E_AGENT_SITE"."WWV_DOCUMENT$" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-02354: error in exporting/importing data
ORA-02367: read ended but had expected more data from file C:\oradata\bkup\STRUTT_PARKER_DOCS39.DMP
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
ORA-39083: Object type OBJECT_GRANT failed to create with error:
ORA-01917: user or role 'ASP3_PUBLIC' does not exist
Failing sql is:
GRANT INSERT ON "E_AGENT_SITE"."WWV_DOCUMENT$" TO "ASP3_PUBLIC"
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TRIGGER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Job "BKUP_USER"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" completed with 2 error(s) at 12:44:16
```

---

Export: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Fri Feb 16 12:00:08 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

;;;

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Starting "BKUP_USER"."STRUTT_PARKER_DOCS": bkup_user/******** parfile=export_docs.par

Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...

Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA

Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 86.55 GB

> > > DBMS_AW_EXP: SYS.AW$EXPRESS: OLAP not enabled
> > >
> > > DBMS_AW_EXP: SYS.AW$AWMD: OLAP not enabled
> > >
> > > DBMS_AW_EXP: SYS.AW$AWCREATE: OLAP not enabled
> > >
> > > DBMS_AW_EXP: SYS.AW$AWCREATE10G: OLAP not enabled
> > >
> > > DBMS_AW_EXP: SYS.AW$AWXML: OLAP not enabled
> > >
> > > DBMS_AW_EXP: SYS.AW$AWREPORT: OLAP not enabled

Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE

Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT

Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX

Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX

Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT

Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS

Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX_STATISTICS

Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TRIGGER

Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS

> > > DBMS_AW_EXP: SYS.AW$EXPRESS: OLAP not enabled
> > >
> > > DBMS_AW_EXP: SYS.AW$AWMD: OLAP not enabled
> > >
> > > DBMS_AW_EXP: SYS.AW$AWCREATE: OLAP not enabled
> > >
> > > DBMS_AW_EXP: SYS.AW$AWCREATE10G: OLAP not enabled
> > >
> > > DBMS_AW_EXP: SYS.AW$AWXML: OLAP not enabled
> > >
> > > DBMS_AW_EXP: SYS.AW$AWREPORT: OLAP not enabled

. . exported "E_AGENT_SITE"."WWV_DOCUMENT$" 76.25 GB 542350 rows

Master table "BKUP_USER"."STRUTT_PARKER_DOCS" successfully loaded/unloaded

Comment: Which database versions are both the source and the target? What says the export LOG file? Does it indicate that something went wrong?

Comment: That is the error given in the log file. Full details now in the original post

Comment: I didn't ask for **import**, but for **export** log file. You've already said that it failed because of ORA-02367. I wanted to see whether export was done correctly (for example, if disk ran out of space, the last DMP file isn't complete).

Comment: My apologies. The third party confirmed that the export completed successfully. The notes they sent me are now in the post.